# view_embed_view doesn't work as expected(Drupal commerce)

Tags: commerce

I want to output the views block of collection_products which is filtered by a taxonomy term but it doesn't print anything when I tried the following code:

print views_embed_view('collection_products','block_1','sample-category-1');

attached is the views editing page.
[image: views editing page]
So what might be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that `sample-category-1` is the correct parameter? Depending on how you set everything up, it might be expecting a taxonomy id or something else instead? Is the contextual filter configured to hide results if nothing matches, change it to display all data, see what happens then. That allows you to discover what is wrong.

Comment: Also you are loading the block, but your screenshot is of the page display, so it is not at all relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use
`$term->term_id` instead of `$term->name` in `views_embed_view()`

You can get it programmatically by loading taxonomy term through `taxonomy_term_load()` function and passing it to `views_embed_view()` as a third argument